# Why doctrine2 not support GROUP_CONCAT(), DATE_FORMAT()?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine2 with Laravel5 and MySql and have some problem with GROUP_CONCAT(), DATE_FORMAT().
I have found the solution by install extension [Beberlei DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions).
And my question is "**Why Doctrine as the big library but not support that normal function in core?**"

Comment: That's something you should ask the author of the said library, not on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine supports [mutiple database engines, not just MySQL](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.7/reference/platforms.html).

The functions you mention are specific to MySQL; other database engines don't have them. The core of Doctrine supports multiple engines, and the extension you mention adds MySQL-specific support.